# Comparing current window or page location to a regular expression. jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, contains

I have two pages, each made up of `divs` that contain location info. Each page currently displays all of the locations in the database, but each page needs to only display locations for one of the two cities. I need to remove all irrelevant locations from each of the two pages. Since I can't put a diff script on each page, I have to differentiate between page location / url.

One of the two cities is Minneapolis, so an example of what I am trying as a regular expression:

```
  new RegExp('^http://([^\.]+)\.domain\.com/contact-us/minneapolis-locations(.*)$');
```

How can I write an `IF` or other statement to check the page location against this regular expression? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using regex, when a simple `indexOf()` would do? (Though admittedly it becomes more cumbersome as the number of cities increases.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [String#match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). It will return an array of matches if any, or null if none exist.

```
var re = new RegExp('^http://([^\.]+)\.domain\.com/contact-us/minneapolis-locations(.*)$');

if(window.location.href.match(re)){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Tried this in Chrome console with an alert inside the IF block. Kicked out an "undefined" error and no alert.

Comment: @SLaks Could you provide an alternative regex?

Comment: @RyanLynch: It has no syntax errors, but it won't work.  `\\` is a string literal escape.  Use a regex literal.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I'm understanding your question.  You want to test the current url against that regular expression in an if statement?

```
var reg = new RegExp('^http://([^\\.]+)\\.domain\\.com/contact-us/minneapolis-locations(.*)$');
if (location.href.match(reg))
{
    ...
}
```

or using a regex literal:

```
var reg = /^http:\/\/([^\.]+)\.domain\.com\/contact-us\/minneapolis-locations(.*)$/;
if (location.href.match(reg))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not my regular expression.  Copied it from the OP.  But yeah, the backslash characters will cause a problem.  Either the regular expression will need to be a regex literal or the backslashes will need to get escaped.